# npm run build = no images

Tags: cordova, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

Here I meet a problem with my project vuejs2 + webpack…

When I make a build for production (npm run build) my images do not appear..

I don't find the place in the webpack config, which the plugin makes a modification to build or what can i do with vuejs to make it.

If anyone has an idea or has already encountered this problem - it would be great!

Screenshots:

[Run on dev is Ok no matter with 3 ways below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmkGV.jpg)

[After build no images, no icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ntZZ.jpg)

Thx all for your responses,

**3 ways with vuejs run dev ok but not in run build**

```
<template>
<div id="test">
    <img :src="urlLogo" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Auth',
  data () {
    return {
      urlLogo: require('../../static/img/mylogo.png')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Or**

```
<template>
<div id="test">
    <img src="/static/img/mylogo.png" />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Or**

```
<template>
<div id="test">
    <img src="~@/assets/img/mylogo.png" />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Here my config/index.js**

```
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.3.1
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  dev: {
    // la config de dev
  },
  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../www/dist/index.html'),
    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../www/dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    /**
     * Source Maps
     */
     productionSourceMap: true,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  }
}
```

**build/webpack.prod.conf.js:**

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : require('../config/prod.env')

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      },
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      parallel: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),
      // Setting the following option to `false` will not extract CSS from codesplit chunks.
      // Their CSS will instead be inserted dynamically with style-loader when the codesplit chunk has been loaded by webpack.
      // It's currently set to `true` because we are seeing that sourcemaps are included in the codesplit bundle as well when it's `false`, 
      // increasing file size: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1110
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
        ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
        : { safe: true }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vendor modules does not change
    //new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks (module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      async: 'vendor-async',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 3
    }),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

**build/build.js:**

```
'use strict'
require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

const ora = require('ora')
const rm = require('rimraf')
const path = require('path')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

const spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stats) => {
    spinner.stop()
    if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false, // If you are using ts-loader, setting this to true will make TypeScript errors show up during build.
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
      console.log(chalk.red('  Build failed with errors.\n'))
      process.exit(1)
    }

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})
```

Comment: Option 2 (`src="/static/img/mylogo.png"`) will not work on Android because the cordova app is actually hosted at `file:///android_asset/www/` on Android, not at the root, so absolute URLs don't work. However, I use Option 1 all the time, and Option 2 with relative URLs (relative to the `.vue` file at compile time) which both work fine. Could you try using Chrome Dev Tools to inspect what is output as the src attribute in the template, within the Android emulator (see [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) for instructions)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code you provided, the first one 'for information', and the second one the cause of your problem.

First off, cordova apps on Android are hosted at `file:///android_asset/www/` , not the root like in the browser, or on iOS. This means that: *absolute URLs won't work with cordova on Android*. You need to change the `src` attribute to use a relative URL, relative to the file on disk containing your template (e.g. your `.vue` file). When webpack processes the file, it will correctly replace the relative URL with one to the image in the bundle.

Secondly (and more importantly), your webpack config doesn't seem to mention anything about `.vue` files, which is where I assume you are storing your Vue.js 2 template, so webpack is not actually processing the `.vue` files. You need to use something like the [vue-loader webpack plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) to allow webpack to process your single-file components.

Take a look at the [documentation for vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/), or use something like the [webpack-simple boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) as a starting point to understand what config you need to include.

You could run the following to quickly get an example working which includes hot-reload:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
vue create hello
cd hello
npm run serve
```

This is the corresponding config that I use with Webpack 2 (it looks like you're using Webpack 1 for some reason) is:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
                        sourceMap: isProduction
                            ? config.build.productionSourceMap
                            : config.dev.cssSourceMap,
                        extract: isProduction
                    })
                }
            },
        ...
    ]
}
```

If you still have problems or can't figure it out, try using [Chrome Dev Tools to debug the app running in the Android emulator](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to explore what ends up running in the emulator. That will give you (me, and others) more clues as to what could be going wrong!