# SvelteKit: no image with npm run build

Tags: npm, build, sveltekit

This is a very simple SvelteKit program:

`<img src="static/bird.jpg" alt="a bird"/>`

When I run it with `npm run dev`, the image is displayed.
But when I use `npm run build` and `npm run preview`, only the alt text is displayed.

What can be the cause?
It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796790/npm-run-build-no-images).

I use SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.107

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution:

`<img src="/bird.jpg" alt="a bird"/>`

Path without `static`.